# Select onChange Table blade view

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

UPDATE : now when i change the poule_id i get a blank table with nothing inside , when i go directly to the url like :

https://mydomaine.eu/go/public/competition/search/equipes?poule_id=2

i get :
table   "\n\n\n\n\n"

I try to make a function who change the result of my blade table who display equipes(teams) with a select box but nothing happen at the moment i don't know where i did a mistake , it's maybe in the javascript code

Hope someone could help to fix that , thanks a lot in advance

I try to change my table depending on poule_id with a select box like this :

```
<select id="poule">
    @foreach($select_poules as $select_poule)
        <option value="{{$select_poule->id}}">{{$select_poule->lb_poule}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

My table contain the teams who depend on a poule_id :

```
@foreach($equipes as $equipe)
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      {!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Here my controller :

```
public function searchEquipes(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->has('poule_id')) {

        $equipes = EquipePoule::where('poule_id' , $request->poule_id)->get();

        $competition = Compet::where('id' , 1)->first();

        $categorie_compet = CategorieCompet::pluck('lb_categorie_compet' , 'id');

        $categorie_age = CatgEquipe::pluck('lb_catg_equipe' , 'id');

        $structure_rattachement = Structure::select('num_structure', 'nom_structure' , 'id')
            ->where('type_structure_id' , '1')
            ->orWhere('type_structure_id' , '2')
            ->orWhere('type_structure_id' , '3')
            ->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
                return [$i->id => $i->num_structure.' - '.$i->nom_structure];
            });
        $poules = Poule::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])->get();

        $rencontres = Rencontre::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])->orderBy('dt_rencontre' , 'DESC')->get();

        $designations = RencontreOfficiel::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])->get();

        $classements = Classement::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])->orderBy('nb_point_classement' , 'DESC')->get();

        $equipe_to_select = Equipe::select('lb_equipe', 'structure_id' , 'catg_equipe_id' ,'id')
            ->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
                return [$i->id => $i->lb_equipe.' - '.$i->structure->nom_structure.' - ' .$i->catg_equipe->lb_catg_equipe];
            });

        $stade = Stade::select('lb_nom', 'ville_stade' ,  'cd_post_stade' ,  'id')
            ->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
                return [$i->id => $i->lb_nom.' - '.$i->ville_stade.' - '.$i->cd_post_stade];
            });



        $find_equipes = $competition->equipes;

        $domicile = $find_equipes->mapWithKeys(function ($i) {
            return [$i->id => $i->lb_equipe.' - '.$i->structure->nom_structure.' - ' .$i->catg_equipe->lb_catg_equipe];
        });


        //ON AFFICHE QUE LES EQUIPES ENREGSITRER DANS LE COMPETITION
        $find_equipes = $competition->equipes;
        $visiteur = $find_equipes->mapWithKeys(function ($i) {
            return [$i->id => $i->lb_equipe.' - '.$i->structure->nom_structure.' - ' .$i->catg_equipe->lb_catg_equipe];
        });

        $select_poules = Poule::where('compet_id' , 1)->get();

        $journees = Journee::where('compet_id' , 1)->get();

        $journee_to_select = Journee::where('compet_id' , 1)->pluck('nm_journee' , 'id');


        return response()->json([

            'table' => view("competitions/show", compact('equipes' , 'competition' , 'categorie_age' , 'categorie_compet' , 'classements' , 'equipe_to_select' , 'structure_rattachement' , 'poules' , 'select_poules' , 'journee_to_select' , 'journees' , 'rencontres', 'designations' , 'stade', 'domicile' , 'visiteur'))->render(),

        ]);

    }else {

        echo 'on trouve rien ';
    }
```

Here my javascript :

```
<script>
    $('#poule').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url : 'search/equipes/',
            data : {
                poule_id : document.getElementById('poule').value
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#equipes').html(data.table);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to inject the whole view using ajax in a div container? Is there any error in the javascript console or php side?

Comment: yes exactly !!! the problem is i get any error in the javascript or php

Comment: I've updated my answer, try following those steps and tell me where the error is so I can provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting no error feedback is quite weird, but I would start by changing the dataType you expect in the ajax function to html, because is unnecessary to cast to json and cast it back to html once in javascript. So it would look like this:

Your controller:

```
public function searchEquipes(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('poule_id')) {
        $equipes = $equipes = EquipePoule::wherePouleId($request->poule_id)->get();
        return view("competitions/show", compact('equipes'))->render();
    }
}
```

Your ajax:

```
<script>
    $('#poule').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "html",
            url : 'search/equipes/',
            data : {
                poule_id : document.getElementById('poule').value
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#equipes').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I would follow some steps to check where the fail is:

- Is the event reaching the ajax?
- Is the ajax reaching the server?
- Is the server routing that call to the controller?
- Is the controller returning the view correctly?
- Is the ajax updating the dom container?

Tell me the point where it fails and I will edit with more info.

Comment: ok so i have some update ! i edit the post , hope you could see where is the problem